# How to permanently store vnodes in browser?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Now, I want without refresh page when redirect page after, I custome keep alive in vuejs, but I can not store vnode, using `JSON.stringify(vnode)`, throw the exception

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'VueComponent'
```

I want to store vnode, when redirect other page after, get the vnode, can not use javascript variable, because redirect page, the javascript variable is null

I want to store vnode forever in the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can save the vnode data instead, like this

```
 import { h } from 'vue'
 function generateVnodeByData(data){
    return h(...data)
 }

 const data = ['div', {class: 'localData'}, []]

 const localNode = generateVnodeByData(data)
```

you can store data to browser and convert data to node in js

Comment: if the page refresh ,the vnode is null ,can not save